# receive Character using Android phone from arduino

Tags: android, arduino, android-bluetooth

I worked this code to receive a single letter of the arduino I can not see  any response on the phone text viewer  when I want arduino  sends the letter 'A' shows me the word 'ON'and if Send 'Z' shows me the word in the text viewer off

Note that the connection between the Android phone arduino been successfully and Android phone sends to arduino  but it did not receive

```
class Ahmed extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        for (; ; ) {
            try {
                int bytesAvailable = btSocket.getInputStream().available();

                byte []packetBytes= new byte[bytesAvailable];
                if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                    tb.setText(bytesAvailable+ "ok");
                    btSocket.getInputStream().read(packetBytes);

                             for(int i=0; i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                             {
                                if (packetBytes[i]==65)
                                     tb.setText("ON");
                                 else if (packetBytes[i] ==90)
                                     tb.setText("off");
                             }
                       }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }


        }
    }
}
```

arduino code

```
   #include<SoftwareSerial.h>
    void setup() {
   Serial3.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
     digitalWrite(13,LOW);
       }

   void loop() {

    char x=Serial3.read();
     if(x=='A')
    {
     digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      Serial3.print('A');
}
 if(x=='Z')
{digitalWrite(13,LOW);
 Serial3.print('Z');
}
}
```

Comment: Line 10 of arduino tries to read a char (blocking operation?) - android never sends anything. ??

Comment: android phone send and there is no problem and  I received from Serial  Monitor but the problem is in the receiving  from android   @ABuckau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are updating textview from a thread, it must be throwing some exception but as you have not printed anything in your **catch block** you are not getting any output or error or anything, always remember, you cannot update views from any thread other than UI thread.

```
        try {
            int bytesAvailable = btSocket.getInputStream().available();

            byte []packetBytes= new byte[bytesAvailable];
            if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                tb.setText(bytesAvailable+ "ok");
                btSocket.getInputStream().read(packetBytes);

                         for(int i=0; i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                         {
                            if (packetBytes[i]==65)
                                 tb.setText("ON");
                             else if (packetBytes[i] ==90)
                                 tb.setText("off");
                         }
                   }

        } catch (Exception e) {
         // ADD THIS TO SEE ANY ERROR 
         e.printStackTrace();            
        }
```

if you are running this thread inside activity class then you can run this

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tb.setText("ON")
            }
        });
```

else you have to implement some mechanism using broadcast receiver or interface for passing the **data** to your **activity/fragment** for updating the **textview** inside **runOnUiThread**.