# How to read from the InputStream on Android bluetooth to TextView from Arduino?

Tags: android

I've been stuck and confused for bytes and buffer code to send a text from Arduino to Android. This is my  Activity.xml (TextView)

```
<TextView
    android:text="Arduino Results"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/jarakbt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

This is some .java code that I don't understand

```
private void startAndroid()
{
    if (btSocket!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("START".toString().getBytes());
            jarakbt.setText(btSocket.getInputStream().read());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            msg("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

And also I provided some Arduino code

```
https://pastebin.com/HFsZvqtr
```

Arduino Serial results in picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF3uA.jpg

So, I am confused. In my Arduino source code, I don't implement any bytes[] blablabla, but all Android source code that I found, implement bytes[] blablabla.

I found a simple problem and i tried it and success. It's 
[receive Character using Android phone from arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39723075/receive-character-using-android-phone-from-arduino)
That source code is for character. As you can see on picture, my results is like "105.72 cm, 1.06 m" and it's not a character...

How can I appear "105.72 cm, 1.06 m" in Android TextView and automatically refresh ?

I am a newbie in Android and Arduino especially Embedded System.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443297/how-to-read-from-the-inputstream-of-a-bluetooth-on-android

Comment: works fine, dude... sorry, i just remembered to reply :D

Comment: No worries man... glad it's working for you